# Set Viewport Meta Parameters Based on the Width of Browser Window

Tags: javascript, meta-tags, viewport

I want to set different parameters for viewport meta tag, depending on the current browser window, and to be able to change them on resize (removing the current viewport meta tag(s) first and then replacing it with the new one. I have a script that I think should do that, but for some reason that script does nothing. I'm missing something, but I can't quite figure out what.

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var width = window.clientWidth; 
var meta = document.createElement("meta");
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

if (width < 960) {  
    meta.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
    meta.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5");
    head.appendChild(meta);
} else {
    meta.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
    meta.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1");
    head.appendChild(meta);
};

window.onresize = function(event) { 
    width = window.clientWidth; 
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
        if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == "viewport") {
            head.removeChild(metas[i]);
        }
    }   
    if (width < 960) {
        meta.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
        meta.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.78");
        head.appendChild(meta);
    } else {
        meta.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
        meta.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1");
        head.appendChild(meta);
    }
};
</script>
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: You need to get the current viewport width in the `onresize` event handler: `width = window.clientWidth;`. You're still using the initial viewport width.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Matt, even with that modification, something is wrong with that script, it's not setting the parameters even without resizing. Thank you very much for spotting the issue inside the event handler! Could you take another look? What else is wrong in this snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `window.clientWidth` may not work in some browsers. A safer way to get the viewport width using plain JavaScript is:

```
var width = window.innerWidth ||
            document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
            document.body.clientWidth;
```

2. There's a typo in the `for` loop. Change the comma to a semi-colon. That typo is causing the code in the `script` tag to crash.

```
for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

3. The current width wasn't getting retrieved in the onresize event handler. It was still using the initial viewport width.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    width = window.innerWidth ||
            document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
            document.body.clientWidth;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it, @Matt. I just tried the corrections that you've suggested. No luck. Even the upper part of the snippet (without the onresize event) doesn't do what it should. Even though for the life of me I can't see why. Thanks in advance for your help!